# Conditional rules for synthetic series in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to get Time Series Vector **node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes** from node-exporter.
It works fine on RHEL7, but this data is absent on RHEL6, due to it is absent in /proc/meminfo on old kernels.

So no problem, Prometheus gives me the possibility to count this Time Series Vector via its rules.

I want to sum **node_memory_MemFree_bytes + node_memory_Buffers_bytes + node_memory_Cached_bytes**.
(It may be not exact but seems good for most cases).

I made such string in Prometheus main config file

```
rule_files:
   - 'prometheus.rules.yml'
```

and such file prometheus.rules.yml:

```
groups:
- name: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes for RHEL6
  rules:
  - record: node_memory_MemAvailableRH6_bytes
    expr: node_memory_MemFree_bytes + node_memory_Buffers_bytes + node_memory_Cached_bytes
    labels:
      sumof: FreeBuffersCached
```

And new Time Series **node_memory_MemAvailableRH6_bytes** appeared.

But... It appeared also for RHEL7 hosts too!

And I can't find how to deal with it.

Is it possible to apply my rule only in condition of absent **node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes**?

Or

Is it possible to ask Grafana to graph **node_memory_MemAvailableRH6_bytes** only if **node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes** is absent?

PS/
I do not want to rewrite node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes by node_memory_MemAvailableRH6_bytes in Prometheus Rules, because my sum is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

New day, fresh brain...
It seems that this makes that I want:

```
- name: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes absent for old kernels
  rules:
  - record: rule:node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes or ( node_memory_MemFree_bytes + node_memory_Buffers_bytes + node_memory_Cached_bytes )
```

Rule writes **node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes** if it is present.

Or **node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes** is created by sum if it is absent.

Note that it is **bad idea** to name record '**node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes**' (I use **rule:node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes**), due to Prom rewrites last result of synthetic metric into new record.